# Apply date value in group by but SELECT statement output field getting DateTime value

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Table Structure:

```
ID   DeviceNumber   CreatedDate
1      101          2018-07-07 07:50:19.0000000
2      101          2018-07-07 01:50:19.0000000
3      101          2018-07-07 06:50:19.0000000
4      101          2018-07-08 02:50:19.0000000
```

Output:

```
ID   DeviceNumber   CreatedDate
1      101          2018-07-07 07:50:19.0000000
2      101          2018-07-08 02:50:19.0000000
```

Here i'm applying `GROUPBY` clause in `CreatedDate` field thats why i seperated Day-Month-Year, but in query output i need `Date` and `Time` in `CreatedDate` field value.

My SQL Statement:

```
SELECT DeviceNumber,  
Convert(varchar(30),Concat(CalMonth, '-' , CalDay, '-' ,CalYear),102)  as CreateDateTime
FROM 
(
select DeviceNumber, DAY(CreatedDate) as CalDay, MONTH(CreatedDate) as CalMonth, YEAR(CreatedDate) as CalYear 
from TableDevice
) AS T
GROUP BY DeviceNumber, CalDay, CalMonth, CalYear
```

In output i need `DeviceNumber` and `CreatedDate` (with Date and Time)

Thanks in an advancd

Comment: share your sample output regarding your input

Comment: If you're grouping by the day, but want the time of the day what are you trying to achieve here? I see no aggregation in your query either, so I can't see any  reason for a a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: If you want to see the date and time together you can't group it.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin updated with output

Comment: @Larnu applying GROUP BY DeviceNumber, CalDay, CalMonth, CalYear

Comment: So is it the `MAX` of that day..? You're comment above explains nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you used the `GROUP BY` in order to merge all the rows with the same day in one, but you still need a time. Which time, though? You need an aggregation function that will return the appropriate one. Since it's called CreatedDate, I bet it's the first one you need (min).

```
select DeviceNumber, min(CreatedDate)
from TableDevice
group by DeviceNumber, convert(date,CreatedDate)
```

The `convert(date,CreatedDate)` is an easier way to group by excluding the time part: The conversion will only keep the date and not the time.

Answer (score 0):

you need `max()`  with group by date

```
select DeviceNumber, max(CreatedDate) as CreatedDate
from TableDevice
group by DeviceNumber, convert(date,CreatedDate)
```

If needs all fields in selection then you can use corelated subquery

```
select t1.* from TableDevice t1
where CreatedDate= (select max(CreatedDate)
                    from TableDevice t2
                    where   convert(date,t2.CreatedDate)=convert(date,t1.CreatedDate)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As previous responses stated you need to specify what time do you want to associate with aggregated date?

But if you wanted to have date and time in separate fields use DATE(CreatedDate) and TIME(CreatedDate)